# Promisifying simple function

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I'm trying to convert this simple function

```
function Foo(a, b, cb) {
    // Do something time consuming...

    var result = 1 + 1;

    cb(result); // .. and finally do the callback.
}
```

to a bluebird.js promise. I've tried to use `Promise.promisify`, but it doesn't work.
So the ultimate goal would be to turn the above to this:

```
Foo(a, b).then(function(result) {
    // ...
});
```

Is that possible? I don't want to use deferreds..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success value should be the second argument:

```
cb(null, result); // .. and finally do the callback.
```

Once you do that using `Promise.promisify` will work.

Note that [the documentation states](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) this:

> The node function should conform to node.js convention of accepting a callback as last argument and calling that callback with error as the first argument and success value on the second argument.